# XSLT transformation on XML doesnt decode special characters like '-',©

Tags: xml, xslt

Im using the below XSLT file to transform my XML, the transformation works fine but in the output XML,
I dont see special characters such as - and © instead I see characters like &#8211 and &#169

I am doing this transformation in Python.

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=" @*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="tire[@name= 'A123']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:attribute name="ABC">348</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:transform>
```

python code:

```
xml = ET.parse('input_xml.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('myfile.xslt')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(xml)
newdom.write('output_xml.xml')
```

I want the output xml to include special characters as it is in input XML,

Comment: Show us the Python code as well.

Comment: @Martin Honnen edited the posted question to include python code

Comment: If I view the output xml in the browser all the special characters are visible, When i view the file in editor I see the characters like &#8211 and &#169

Comment: Does using `newdom.write_output('output_xml.xml')` give you the expected result? I think the lxml documentation suggests that that method is set up to use the `xsl:output` properties while the plain `write` might use a different encoding: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects

Comment: Not sure of the Python API for this, but I would suggest transforming direct to serialized output (and thus using the XSLT processor's serializer) rather than transforming to a DOM result tree and then serializing the DOM.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, You were absolutely right about it, I found out that newdom.write was not using the xsl:output properties....Followed your suggestion...works fine now :) Thank you for the great help!!

Comment: I have morphed the suggestion from the comment into an answer so that you can mark your question as resolved by accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lxml documentation at https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects suggests that is is advisable to use the method `write_output` instead of the `write` method to serialize the result of an XSLT transformation as only `write_output` takes any `xsl:output` settings into account.